# Paint program not using parallel arrays to store size and color properly

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, paintcomponent

It's a simple Paint-style program based on the use of arrays and arraylists to save the coordinates, sizes, and colors of different points draw on the screen using a JFrame, paintComponent, and various mouse listeners.

I recently fixed a problem where it would spit out an ArrayOutOfBounds error and point to line 34 with the colors array exceeding its limit of 10000. However I need the program to run and the size and color of each point parallel to each other, so each time the program repaints the points, each retains its own size and color variables. Thank you for your input!

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Proj1Panel extends JPanel{
        public int SIZE = 5, c = 0, s = 0;

        private ArrayList<Point> pointList;
        public int[] sizes;
        public Color[] colors;

        public Proj1Panel(){
            pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
            sizes = new int[10000];
            colors = new Color[10000];

            addMouseListener (new Proj1Listener());
            addMouseMotionListener (new Proj1Listener());
            addMouseWheelListener (new Proj1Listener());

            setBackground(Color.black);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics page){
            super.paintComponent(page);
            for(Point spot : pointList){
                page.setColor(colors[c]);
                page.fillRect(spot.x-sizes[pointList.size()], spot.y-sizes[pointList.size()], sizes[pointList.size()]*2, sizes[pointList.size()]*2);
                c = 0;
            }
            repaint();
            page.setColor(Color.RED);
            page.fillRect(5, 40, 30, 30);
            page.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            page.fillRect(5, 75, 30, 30);
            page.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            page.fillRect(5, 110, 30, 30);
            page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            page.fillRect(5, 145, 30, 30);
            page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            page.drawString("Count: " + pointList.size() + "/10000", 5, 15);
            page.drawString("Size: " + SIZE, 5, 30);
        }
        private class Proj1Listener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener{
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
                pointList.add(event.getPoint());
                sizes[pointList.size()] = SIZE;
                repaint();
            }
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
                pointList.add(event.getPoint());
                sizes[pointList.size()] = SIZE;
                repaint();
            }
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event){
                SIZE -= event.getWheelRotation();
                repaint();
            }
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
                int x1 = event.getX();
                int y1 = event.getY();
                if(x1 > 5 && x1 < 35 && y1 > 40 && y1 < 70){
                    colors[c] = Color.RED;
                }
                if(x1 > 5 && x1 < 35 && y1 > 75 && y1 < 105){
                    colors[c] = Color.BLUE;
                }
                if(x1 > 5 && x1 < 35 && y1 > 110 && y1 < 140){
                    colors[c] = Color.GREEN;
                }
                if(x1 > 5 && x1 < 35 && y1 > 145 && y1 < 175){
                    colors[c] = Color.WHITE;
                }
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){}
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){}
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event){}
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to fix the problem I had with my program. I had to reset a couple variables before I the drawing loop. Here is the working program!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Proj1Panel extends JPanel{
    public int SIZE = 5, c = 0, s = 0;
    private ArrayList<Point> pointList;
    private int[] sizes;
    private Color[] colors;
    public String colorIs = "WHITE";

    public Proj1Panel(){
        pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
        sizes = new int[1000000];
        colors = new Color[1000000];

        addMouseListener (new Proj1Listener());
        addMouseMotionListener (new Proj1Listener());
        addMouseWheelListener (new Proj1Listener());

        setBackground(Color.black);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page){
        super.paintComponent(page);
        page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        c = 0;
        s = 0;
        for(Point spot : pointList){
            page.setColor(colors[c]);
            page.fillRect(spot.x-sizes[s], spot.y-sizes[s], sizes[s]*2, sizes[s]*2);
            c++;
            s++;
        }
        repaint();
        page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        page.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 35);
        page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        page.fillRect(0, 35, 40, 180);
        page.setColor(Color.RED);
        page.fillRect(5, 40, 30, 30);
        page.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        page.fillRect(5, 75, 30, 30);
        page.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        page.fillRect(5, 110, 30, 30);
        page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        page.fillRect(5, 145, 30, 30);
        page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        page.fillRect(5, 180, 30, 30);
        page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        page.fillRect(7, 182, 26, 26);
        page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        page.drawString("Count: " + pointList.size() + "/1000000", 5, 15);
        page.drawString("Size: " + SIZE, 5, 30);
        page.drawString("Color: ", 65, 30);
        page.drawString(colorIs, 100, 30);
    }
    private class Proj1Listener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener{
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
            pointList.add(event.getPoint());
            sizes[pointList.size()] = SIZE;
            repaint();
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
            pointList.add(event.getPoint());
            sizes[pointList.size()] = SIZE;
            repaint();
        }
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event){
            SIZE -= event.getWheelRotation();
            repaint();
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
            int x1 = event.getX();
            int y1 = event.getY();
            if(x1 > 5 && x1 < 35 && y1 > 40 && y1 < 70){
                colors[c] = Color.RED;
                colorIs = "RED";
            }
            if(x1 > 5 && x1 < 35 && y1 > 75 && y1 < 105){
                colors[c] = Color.BLUE;
                colorIs = "BLUE";
            }
            if(x1 > 5 && x1 < 35 && y1 > 110 && y1 < 140){
                colors[c] = Color.GREEN;
                colorIs = "GREEN";
            }
            if(x1 > 5 && x1 < 35 && y1 > 145 && y1 < 175){
                colors[c] = Color.WHITE;
                colorIs = "WHITE";
            }
            if(x1 > 5 && x1 < 35 && y1 > 180 && y1 < 210){
                colors[c] = Color.black;
                colorIs = "BLACK";
            }
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){}
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event){}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming it crashes on `sizes[pointList.size()] = SIZE;` but could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: do you know what line the error comes from?

Comment: I went back and included the error code that the console swings. It says the problem is in the for(Points spot : pointList) loop in the paintComponent class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never reset the c variable, used as an index to the color array, to 0 in the paintComponent method. Instead it is set to 0 once in the beginning of the program. Thus it will monotonically increase until the array overflows. Consider resetting it to 0 at the beginning of paintComponent.

Also, what kind of Point class are you using? It holds some array, that we are not seeing. Here:

```
spot.x-sizes[pointList.size()]
```

---

**Edit**
I apologize as I misread your code, and I also didn't explain my answer well. You still should increment the `c` variable, but you should re-set it to 0 at the **beginning** of paintcomponent. For example:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
  super.paintComponent(page);
  c = 0;  // each time paintComponent starts, c should be 0
  for (Point spot : pointList) {
     page.setColor(colors[c]);
     page.fillRect(spot.x - sizes[pointList.size()], spot.y
           - sizes[pointList.size()], sizes[pointList.size()] * 2,
           sizes[pointList.size()] * 2);
     c++;  // but within the for loop, it should increment.
  }
  // .... etc
```

Alternatively, don't use a for-each loop, but rather a basic for loop, and this way you wouldn't even need a `c` variable.

Comment: That removes the ArrayOutOfBounds error, but now it only saves the color for the first element in my colors array. I'm trying to get to where the program will save each point with its own size and color as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: @TristanWright: we need to see your Point class. You are only drawing one index's Point each time, which confuses me.

Comment: The `pointList` is an ArrayList that is declared in the `Proj1Panel` class beginning. As far as I know, the MouseListener picks up on where the mouse clicks, then saves the point as an element in `pointList`, recalling it later, along with the size it is after the last point was added.

Comment: @TristanWright: spot is a Point variable, but on looking up the API for `java.awt.Point`, I don't say any `x-sizes` array field in it. This is one thing that confuses me.

Comment: That's the thing, my professor expects each point in the `pointList` to be drawn on the frame with its own corrisponding size and color, pointing back to the two parallel arrays of `sizes` and `colors`. I'm pretty stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom object to containing the information you need to do the painting. That is your custom object can contain the Color and the Rectangle that you want to paint.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of how this can be done, then change your code to use the custom Object. You would use the `DrawOnComponent` example.

> my professor expects each point in the pointList to be drawn on the frame with its own corrisponding size and color, pointing back to the two parallel arrays of sizes and colors.

I just read that above comment, so my suggestion doesn't help. However, it still would not hurt to look at the example to see that each time you add a "point" top the ArrayList, you need to also set the Color and Size at the same time. Even though my code uses a Rectangle, the same logic is required for your code as well.

Also, why would you have one data structure as an ArrayList and two other structures as an Array. (Tell the prof) that is a terrible requirement. The ArrayList can grow to any size, but the Arrays are hard code to a magic number of 1000.